# How to get the name of the file just now i have uploaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to upload directory.From there i am trying to insert the entire file into the database.Here is a script which tells how i uploaded the file.I need the name of the file that i just uploaded for inserting the data into the database.
 here is the script

Controller/FileUploadsController.php

```
    <?php
    class FileUploadsController extends AppController {
    public Function index(){

    // A list of permitted file extensions
    $allowed = array('csv');


       if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

          $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
          echo $extension;


          if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
              echo '{"status":"error"}';
              exit;
          }

          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){;
              echo '{"status":"success"}';
              exit;
          }
       }

       echo '{"status":"error"}';
       exit;
    }
 }
```

View/FileUploads/index.ctp

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Mini Ajax File Upload Form</title>

        <!-- Google web fonts -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel='stylesheet' />

        <!-- The main CSS file -->
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="upload" method="post" action="FileUploads" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="drop">
                Drop Here

                <a>Browse</a>
                <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
            </div>

            <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
            </ul>

        </form>

        <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

        <!-- Our main JS file -->
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>


        <!-- Only used for the demos. Please ignore and remove. --> 
        <script src="http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/misc/enhance/v1.js" async></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(function(){

    var ul = $('#upload ul');

    $('#drop a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    $('#upload').fileupload({

        // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
        dropZone: $('#drop'),

        // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
        // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
        add: function (e, data) {

            var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
                ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

            // Append the file name and file size
            tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                         .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

            // Add the HTML to the UL element
            data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

            // Initialize the knob plugin
            tpl.find('input').knob();

            // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
            tpl.find('span').click(function(){

                if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                    jqXHR.abort();
                }

                tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                    tpl.remove();
                });

            });

            // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
            var jqXHR = data.submit();
        },

        progress: function(e, data){

            // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
            // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
            data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

            if(progress == 100){
                data.context.removeClass('working');
            }
        },

        fail:function(e, data){
            // Something has gone wrong!
            data.context.addClass('error');
        }

    });


    // Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
    $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Helper function that formats the file sizes
    function formatFileSize(bytes) {
        if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
            return '';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }

        return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
    }

});
```

it is a simple jquery file uploader script working file.there might be a problem in FileUploadsController.php. I need help in getting the name of the file that uploaded.

Comment: Doesn't this give you the name of file: echo $_FILES['upl']['name']; ?

Comment: i did echo $_FILES['upl']['name']  ; and exit(); nothing it is echoing.

Comment: $name = $_FILES['upl']['name']; i assigned this to a variable and further used for creating table.but the control not going after move(source,dest) ; only

Comment: And Did you try echo $_FILES['upl']['tmp_name']; ?

Comment: I exit the code by echoing some string after move() that string also not echoing.I am surprised for moving it is considering $_FILES['upl']['name'].But after moving not even a single line is excecuting.

Comment: And the other thing is it is a already available plugin.Url is:https://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form.I downloaded and edited according to my view and Controller name

Comment: Is your file saving on your destination folder. It seems the control is not coming towards your if block. and please review once again your  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){; block I found semicolon after a bracket

Comment: Yes.all kinds of csv files are moving to the specified Uploads folder

Comment: I removed the semicolon and then i tested.then also i am not able to get the filename.Control is not coming after move statement itself

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: no i did not.if i echo anything in php part it wont work for sure because i am uploading the file by using ajax. i am trying to get the uploaded file name in php.